# nodejs View not rending in Layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript

I am trying to create a simple layout using CoffeeScript, NodeJS and expressJS. My Coffee script is

**routes.coffee** I have renamed routes folder to apps and my routes.coffee file is in there in authentication folder i.e. `apps\authentication\routes.coffee`

```
routes = (app) ->
  app.get "/login", (req , res) ->
    res.render "#{__dirname}/views/login",
      title: 'Login',
      stylesheet: 'login'
module.exports = routes
```

**Login View** I have renamed routes folder to apps and my login view in there in authentication folder i.e. `apps\authentication\views\login.jade`

```
extends ../../../views/layout

block content
form(action='/sessions', method='post')
    label
        | Username
        input(type='text', name='user')
    label
        | Password
        input(type='password', name='password')
    input(type='submit', name='Submit')
```

**Layout.jade** This file is in default views folder. I am using default layout

```
doctype
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    #content
      h1= title
      block content

    != body
```

**app.js**

```
require('coffee-script').register();
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//var index = require('./routes/index');
//var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
// app.set('view options', { layout: 'views/layout' });
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
// app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view options', {  
  layout: false
});
//app.use('/', index);
//app.use('/users', users);

require('./apps/authentication/routes')(app);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I have created two variables `title` and `stylesheet` in `routes.coffee` however, when i try to implement those variables at `layout.jade` i.e. title, i get `undefined` as title in heading.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find source of the problem? Because I am trying to reflect this situation and I do not encounter your issue..

Comment: no, I am at same level.

Comment: Hey @Aqdas, do you get any trace back or errors in your console?

Comment: no i am not getting error or anything in console. my complete code is above and you can copy paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not used indentation correctly. In your Login View this :

```
extends ../../../views/layout

block content
form(action='/sessions', method='post')
    label
        | Username
        input(type='text', name='user')
    label
        | Password
        input(type='password', name='password')
    input(type='submit', name='Submit')
```

should be :

```
extends ../../../views/layout
block content
  form(action='/sessions', method='post')
    label
        | Username
        input(type='text', name='user')
    label
        | Password
        input(type='password', name='password')
    input(type='submit', name='Submit')
```

Comment: Pleasure @Aqdas